# Probability least number of tosses of a pair of dice

Tags: probability

A pair of dice is tossed repeatedly. What is the least number of tosses needed so that the probability of getting a 11 will be greater than a) 0.5 b) 0.95

Answer (score 2):

Let me help you to answer your own question. I will not give you the full answer but I'm sure you'll be able to compute it afterwards.

If we throw once, the probability of throwing $11$ is $\frac{2}{36}=\frac{1}{18}$. So if we thrown $n$ times, what is the probability that we have not yet thrown $11$? That's right: 
$P_n=(\frac{17}{18})^n$ 
We are interested in the $n$ such that $1-P_n$ exceeds a) 0.5 and b) 0.95.

Can you pick it up from here? Try first finding equality and then looking at which side of the equality your amount of tosses should lie. Good luck!

Comment: It should be (1/18)^n right?

Comment: Almost. For one dice throw that is true. However note that $1-P_n=1-(\frac{17}{18})^n \neq (\frac{1}{18})^n$

Comment: We also consider throwing 11 multiple times.

Comment: Ok. Will the equality be 1 - (17/18)^n = 0.5

Comment: Yes. Remember that $1-\left(\frac{17}{18}\right)^n$ is the probability of throwing 11 at least once in $n$ throws. The question is to find the $n$ such that this exceeds certain values.